# Tomcat7 on docker - not responding issue

Tags: tomcat, docker, jvm

We have a tomcat7 running on top of docker container (official docker image).
On rush hours after some time the tomcat hangs and no longer able to serve reqeusts (many requests are stuck and waiting indefinitely).

Here is the 'manager-app' details:

**JVM**

Free memory: 627.21 MB Total memory: 1751.50 MB Max memory: 10923.00 MB

**http-apr-8080**

Max threads: 500 Current thread count: 500 Current thread busy: 500 Keeped alive sockets count: 0
Max processing time: 871759 ms Processing time: 412926.78 s Request count: 3466023 Error count: 326 Bytes received: 354.74 MB Bytes sent: 1371.40 MB

**Connections Section**

X500 entries like this:

S   166957 ms   0 KB    0 KB ip1 ip2    api.app.url POST /do1 HTTP/1.1
...

Any ideas why this happens?

P.S - It seems that the total memory is too low (considering the free memory is significantly low) what could cause that?

Answer (score 0):

Java application may not run as expected in container like Docker , it's mostly related to the garbage collection not giving enough cpu quota with a lot of running thread it can get worst.

I suggest you took a look at the garbage collection log and analyze Full GC it may indicate a memory pressure , and to the cpu utilization as well.

Take a look at this [article](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/11/application-pauses-when-running-jvm-inside-linux-control-groups) it may help